# How to insert a value from JS into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I just need to someone to direct me in how I would take values from a javascript page and insert them into a html page in a table rather than have one chunk of values being fed back to me, cheers.

```
    Javascript:
document.write(''
     + 'Browser Name: ' + objbrowserName + '<br>'
     + 'Full Version: ' + objfullVersion + '<br>'
     + 'Major Version: ' + objbrowserName + " " + objBrMajorVersion + '<br>'
     + 'Navigator Name: ' + navigator.appName + '<br>'
     + 'Navigator UserAgent: ' + navigator.userAgent + '<br>'
     + 'Operating System: ' + OSName + '<br>'
     + 'Cookies Enabled: ' + Cookies + '<br>'
     + 'Java Enabled: ' + Java + '<br>'
     + 'Flash Player Version: ' + version + '<br>'
     + 'WebSockets Supported: ' + WebSocket + '<br>'
     + 'Browser Size: ' + BrowserW + " x " + BrowserH + '<br>'
     + 'Screen Size: ' + ScreenW + " x " + ScreenH + '<br>'
     + 'Colour Depth: ' + Depth + '<br>'
    )
```

This is what is returned:

```
  Browser Name: Chrome
Full Version: 41.0.2272.89
Major Version: Chrome 41
Navigator Name: Netscape
Navigator UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Operating System: Windows
Cookies Enabled: True
Java Enabled: True
Flash Player Version: 17,0,0
WebSockets Supported: True
Browser Size: 500 x 420
Screen Size: 1280 x 1024
Colour Depth: 24 bit
```

However I want to be able break up the data into a table with 2 columns but i'm confused as to how to get the data from the JS file.

Comment: Can you provide a basic jsbin with the data you're after?

Comment: @EdwardKnowles  I amended the original post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is solution

**Javascript**

```
 <script>
 function get_value(){
  var BrowserName = objbrowserName;
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = BrowserName;
 }
 </script>
```

**Html**

```
 <div id="mydiv"></div>
 <button type="button" onclick="get_value();">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: I need it to appear on load, not as a button but thanks one step closer :)

Comment: @luke you simply use this window.onload = function(){
    // your code goes here
}